# permutations of elements of vector

Tags: notation, permutations, vectors

I'm trying to find a simple representation of a set I can describe with words, but not mathematically...  probably a simple question..

Consider some two-element vector $q=(q_1,q_2)$.

How can I define a function $\mathcal{P}(q)$ that takes in a vector $q$ and returns the set of unique permutations of $\{\pm q_1,\pm q_2\}$, where $q_1$ and $q_2$ are positive integers?

So if $q=(1,0)$, I want $\mathcal{P}(q)=\{(1,0),(-1,0),(0,1),(0,-1)\}$.

If $q=(2,1)$, I want $\mathcal{P}(q)=\{(2,1),(-2,1),(2,-1),(-2,-1),(1,2),(1,-2),(1,-2),(-1,-2)\}$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's not at all a simple question, and is in fact quite fertile with pretty contemporary research.

Permuting entries and possibly multiplying them by $-1$ is really a very natural thing for a *group* to do, and consequently the language of groups is the most natural way to express such a thing.

First, we'll need a bunch of (eight) linear transformations that correspond to [symmetries of a square](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~eb/d4/); call this group $B_2$ for mysterious reasons. This group consists of matrices like $$\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},$$ which switches the $x$- and $y$-coordinates by reflecting across the line $y = x$, and $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix},$$ which sends a point $(x, y)$ to $(x, -y)$ by reflecting across the $x$-axis.

With all of this in place, we can give a really compact definition, essentially given by Fomin and Reading in their lecture notes [Root Systems and Generalized Associahedra](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0505/0505518v3.pdf).

Given any point $q$ the set of vectors you're after is just *the orbit of $q$ under the action of $B_2$*! In symbols, it's the set $\{T(q): T \in B_2\}$.

What's neat about this approach is that it generalizes in really interesting ways. This is because $n$-dimensional cubes always have a group of symmetries that we can write down as linear transformations, and we can always let them act on an $n$-dimensional vector and see what happens after all the transformations have had a turn.

With a good choice of starting vector $q$ in $\Bbb R^3$, we get this beauty

[image]

(image from Stefan Forcey's [website](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~sf34/hedra.htm#TypeBPermutohedron)), which is combinatorially equivalent to a truncated cuboctahedron, an Archimedean Solid. Its mysterious name is the type $B_3$ permutohedron.

---

I realize this may not have been the answer you were expecting. In my opinion, it's because you've allowed a fairly complicated group to do the acting. If you were just permuting coordinates, it would be easier to write down in a pretty self-contained way (obtaining the classical, or type A, permutohedra), using permutations and the symmetric group.

For the set you want, let $[n]$ be shorthand for the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ (it's frankly too much work to write down and not generalize to higher dimensions! Just use $n = 2$ in two dimensions). We'll need

- the set $S_n$ of permutations $\sigma: [n] \to [n]$,
- the set $F$ of all functions $f: [n] \to \{1, -1\}$, and finally
- the notation $q_i$ to mean the $i$th component of your point $q$.

Then your set of points would be

$$\Big\{\big( f(1)q_{\sigma(1)}, f(2)q_{\sigma(2)}, \ldots, f(n)q_{\sigma(n)} \big) : f \in F, \sigma \in S_n\Big\}.$$

It looks awful, and now you see why I've hidden it at the end here!

Comment: wow, OK, thanks for all that! will take some time to digest..

Comment: Sure! I enjoy this stuff, so I couldn't help myself there. If anything isn't clear, just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is . For each element there are $2$ ways  $+$ and $-$ respectively  so for $n$ elements there are $2^n$ thus tgese are total number of unique combinations but as you have edited n different terms can be arranged in $n!$ ways so total ways are $n!.2^n$ and if terms are repeating ie $|x|$ is same then its $\frac{n!}{p!}2^n$

Comment: thanks archis. I wasn't clear in my question, so I've reposed it.

Comment: i should also mention that your answer isn't quite accurate...  I gave two examples with same number of elements with different number of unique permutations.  Although, this is not what I was looking to answer..

Comment: No $0$ is an exception for +,-

Comment: here is another example $q=(1,1)$, $\mathcal{P}(q)=\{(1,1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(-1,-1)\}$.

Comment: If you clear it in question tgen it would be much easier i think