# Orbitopes of finite groups are symmetric convex polytopes

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, convex-analysis, polytopes

I am reading the following paper:

- Raman Sanyal, Frank Sottile, Bernd Sturmfels, [Orbitopes](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.5436), arXiv:0911.5436.

In the first page, the paper says "Orbitopes of finite groups are symmetric convex polytopes".

Consider an orbit $\mathcal{O}$ of $x_0$ under the finite group $G$

1. Convexity:
   Because of an orbitope is the convex hull of an orbit.
2. Symmetry:
   If this is the group with operator "addition", $g\in G$ guarantees $-g\in G$, then it is not hard to think about "symmetry" since we have $-gx_0, gx_0$. However it the operator is "multiplication", how to explain this? Or even more, the operator is composition.
3. I also have no idea how to view it as a polytopes.  Could anyone give me a strict way to view it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the things orbitopes are meant to generalize? Permutohedra are good examples -- even the "classical" permutohedron. By design, the group acts transitively on the vertices, and the polytope is the convex hull of those vertices, it "inherits" the group as its group of symmetries (I assume at least). See page 21 of [Fomin and Reading](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0505518v3.pdf) and possibly some of their references for a start (possibly [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1627956/120540) too).

Comment: If the group is the trivial group, then clearly the convex hull of an orbit is not symmetric unless it contains zero.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Why is it not symmetric?